# Difference between control string in printf function and scanf function

Tags: c, string, printf, controls, scanf

Difference between the control string in printf function and scan function?

I want to know the answer

Comment: `scanf` and `printf` are two very different functions, therefore your question is hard to answer. Read the documentation of these functions, the answer is most likely there.

Comment: One difference is the way that a `*` is used in the format specifier. And the width specifier has different behaviour. Another difference is what whitespace in the format string  does. One frequent error is overlooking that `scanf` *requires* `%lf` to scan a `double` value whereas `printf` uses `%f` to output a `double` value.

Comment: The `%i` specifier in `printf` outputs in decimal. When used in `scanf` it can accept input in decimal, octal, or hexadecimal notation. For this reason you should not use `%i` in `scanf` *unless* the user understands and needs the varying formats.

Comment: It appears that, once upon a time, the intent was that any formatted output you could print using `printf`, you could scan back in using `scanf`, and using more or less the same format string.  Certainly there are a lot of compatibilities between `printf` and `scanf` format strings.  But there are also a lot of *in*compatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Some differences:

1. `"%d"` and other number formats match `int` (a simple type) with `printf()` and `int *` with `scanf()` (a pointer to a simple type).
2. `"*"` in a *specifier* indicates a *width*/*precision* in `printf()` and to not save the scanned item in `scanf()`.
3. `printf()` returns printed character count. `scanf()` returns conversion count.
4. `"%f"` and `"%lf"` both match `double` with `printf()`. With `scanf()`, they match `float *` and `double *`.
5. `scanf()` has no *precision* control.  `printf()` does.
6. `scanf()` should be avoided when input may not be well formed.
7. `"%p"` exists in `printf()`, but not `scanf()`.
8. `"%[...]"` exists in `scanf()`, but not `printf()`.
9. A whitespace in `scanf()` consumes 0 or more any white spaces.  In `printf()`, it is always printed as is.
10. A *width* in `scanf()` is the maximum number of characters to scan.  With `printf()`, it is the minimum number of characters to print.

Many more ...